# Копирование файлов с проверкой

Tags: linux, bash

Сделал простенький bash скрип копирующий загруженные файлы с разных директорий в разные диски. Иногда диски заполняются до максимума.

Можно ли проверить при копировании вместится файл или нет, при условии что на диске должно
остаться 1ГБ свободного места, независимо от размера диска? Например диск 150ГБ, должно использоваться 149ГБ и 1ГБ свободным.

Comment: можно. а судя по изложенному вами алгоритму — даже и нужно. программа `df`, вызванная как `$ df /путь/к/файлу/или/каталогу` покажет (в том числе и) размер оставшегося свободного пространства в файловой системе, где располагается указнный файл/каталог.

Comment: Смысл в том, как остановить копирование или перемещение, если файл не вмещается на диск.

Comment: получить размер файла, получить размер свободного файлового пространства, сравнить, действовать соответствуюим образом, основываясь на результатах сравнения.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, неатомарный это способ. ТС: вначале надо попытаться зарезервировать место под файл, если эта операция провалилась — места нет.

Comment: Есть штатные инструменты для резервирования места перед копированием или перемещением?

Comment: Я думаю, вам надо смотреть в сторону `rsync`.